# Converting a Google doc to PDF, then moving to another folder

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script

I am working on script that will fill a Google doc template with cell values from a spreadsheet. A copy of the edited doc is created and converted into a PDF. I would then like for both the doc and the pdf to be moved to the specified folder. I am stuck on getting the pdf moved over to the folder. I created a function to move the docs, and it seems to work fine with the Google doc copy, but an error is being returned when the function runs for the pdf. The error seems to be coming from the moveFile function. I have also tried moving moveFile pdf call to fillLetter, but still get the same error. This is my first attempt at coding with Google script, so any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
function fillLetter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];//Form Responses tab
  var templateId = '1d-CKr_Xi27FrWsH6eWdUCWKyzrLjy3ivTjLkk_WyJ4s';//Test doc

  //get candidates row number from user input
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var rowNum = ui.prompt("Please enter candidate row number");

  //activates first column in selected row
  var col = sheet.getRange("A"+ rowNum.getResponseText());
  sheet.setActiveRange(col);
  var candName = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();

  col = sheet.getRange("B"+ rowNum.getResponseText());
  sheet.setActiveRange(col);
  var location = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();

  //creates copy of template doc and renames
  var lastName = candName.split(" ");
  var filename = candName.substring(0,1) + lastName[lastName.length - 1] + ' - Offer Letter';
  var newOffer = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy();
  var offerId = newOffer.getId();
  DriveApp.getFileById(offerId).setName(filename);

  //gets body of template doc and replaces text
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(offerId);
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var todaysDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'PST', 'MMMM dd, yyyy');
  body.replaceText('{{Todays date}}', todaysDate);
  body.replaceText('{{Candidate name}}', candName);
  body.replaceText('{{Location}}', location);
  

  doc.saveAndClose();

  //Creates folder and moves newly created files
  var folderName = DriveApp.createFolder(candName).getId();
  convertPDF(offerId, folderName); // Line 52
  moveFile(offerId, folderName);
  
}

function convertPDF(fileToCopy, folder) {
  var docFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder);
  var copy = DriveApp.getFileById(fileToCopy);
  //Add the PDF extension 
  var docblob = copy.getAs('application/pdf');
  docblob.setName(copy.getName() + ".pdf");
  var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);
  var fileId = pdfFile.getId();
  Logger.log("Offer PDF id - " + fileId);//for debug
  moveFile(fileId, docFolder); // Line 66
}

function moveFile(fileId, folderId) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).addFile(file); // Line 72: wh/ error is most likely occurring
}
```

Below is the error message from the Logger:

```
Error   
Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp.
moveFile    @ testCode.gs:72
convertPDF  @ testCode.gs:66
fillLetter  @ testCode.gs:52
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current stage, you can use `moveTo` method for moving the file on Google Drive. This has added on July 27, 2020. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2020#july_27_2020) In your script, when `moveFile` is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function moveFile(fileId, folderId) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  file.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId));
}
```

#### Reference:

- [moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination)

  - The methods of addFile, addFolder, removeFile and removeFolder have already been deprecated. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#deprecated-methods_1)